# What is the expected time frame for FAA knowledge test results to show up in IACRA?

Tags: pilot-certification, faa-knowledge-test, remote-pilot

I just passed my Part 107 Remote Pilot's knowledge test this morning, and I noticed that IACRA indicates it may take up to 48 hours for the test records to show up.  Does it always take 48 hours or is it sometimes faster than that?  What is the soonest that I might reasonably expect the test results to appear?

Bonus points if anyone knows why it takes so long, but I realize that may not be something anyone knows about (or can talk about).

Comment: Mine went through at about 35 hours after I finished the test.  Now to see how real the 7 days for the temp cert is.

Answer (score 2):

I passed back in December 2016.  Took 3 days to get temp license and about 90 days to get my perm license.  Took me a week of study watching Youtube videos on weather and sectionals, in conjunction with UAS107 prep app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uas107.openrobotix.labs&hl=en)

Comment: Do you recall how long it took for the test to be available in IACRA so you could process the application.  I was able to find pretty good info on timings for the rest of the process, but nothing on when I should expect the test itself to show up.  Trying to avoid trying again every few hours if it's going to take a while.